# OpenLayers 4 between geometry

Tags: openlayers, distance, geometry

I want to know the distance between two drawn geometries. I look for it and saw in OpenLayers 2 the distanceTo methods but I actually use OpenLayers 4. I know there is haversine method but it's between two points.

Did you know any way to calculate the distance in the last version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [JSTS](http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/doc/api/jsts.operation.distance.DistanceOp.html) to calculate the distance between your two geometries.  There's an [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/jsts.html) among those of OpenLayers that features JSTS, i.e. it shows how to use `buffer` but you could try to see from there how you could use the distance operator in JSTS.